# PostgreSQL sum of intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

In my database I have rows like:

```
date    , value
16:13:00, 500
16:17:00, 700
16:20:00, 0
```

Now I want to do "special sum" over value from 16:00:00 to 17:00:00. So until 16:13 we assume that we have 0.
So special sum would look like (I'll omit seconds):

```
...
0 +     -- (16:12)
500 +   -- (16:13)
500 +   -- (16:14)
500 +   -- (16:15)
500 +   -- (16:16)
700 +   -- (16:17)
700 +   -- (16:18)
700 +   -- (16:19)
0 +     -- (16:20)
...
```

So I have in database only changes of value and when this change occurs. And I want to sum over the whole hour. Result of this should be 4100.
What is the optimal way of doing that kind of sum in sql with PostgreSQL?

Best

Comment: Please add what is your required output. If this is only 4100 then answers below are correct. For missing time units, it is best practise to use `generate_series()` to generate all possible time intervals and then `left join` your data and do the aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

You could at first select only the hour of your timestamp and then group by this hour:

```
SELECT
  sum(s.value),
  s.hour
FROM
  (SELECT
    value,
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time) as hour
  FROM la_table) as s
GROUP BY s.hour
```

This way you would just get values from 15:00:00 to 15:59:59 of course.

SQLFiddle for playing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d6ad1/1

Comment: Yes that is true, but you are missing the values "in between". In database you don't have "all values". My database includes only "changes".

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you are looking for simply totals per hour?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(hour FROM "date") hr,
       SUM(value) total
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY hr
ORDER BY hr;
```

Comment: I don't have all data in database. I have only "change events" e.g. `16:13:00, 500; 16:17:00, 700; 16:20:00, 0` from these values I have to come up to sum of `4100`.

Comment: Can you clarify further? If you have the hour (from the "change events"), then why won't using EXTRACT as I've demonstrated above be sufficient? Did you test the query and see if returns what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you wish to select every entries with occurance within a time period.  In this example any row with a time value within 10:00 and 11:00 is selected if it stars before the period or during the period or if it ends during the period of after the period.

```
select * from table 
   where table.start_time < end_of_period and table.end_time > end_of_period

select * from table
   where (start_time < '2017-05-16 11:00:00') and (end_time > '2017-05-16 10:00:00')
```